# Can the buttons be in the center of the page using position:absolute;?

Tags: html, css

this is my simple html

```css
a { text-decoration: none; }
.button-one {
    background: #edf000; /* background color */
}
.button-two {
    background: #f15640;
}
.button-three {
    background: #27c9b8;
}
.button-one,
.button-two,
.button-three {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.button-one:hover,
.button-two:hover,
.button-three:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a class="button-one" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Click Me</a>

<a class="button-two" title="Relevant Title" href="#">No Click Me</a>

<a class="button-three" title="Relevant Title" href="#">No Me LOL</a>
```

but when i try to add the position:absolute; The buttons become very bad

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
-ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
transform:translateY(-50%);
```

I want the same result as the first but in the middle of the page
where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply wrap them inside a `div` and center them using `flexbox`. It is more easier, like so:

```css
.links{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  gap:10px;
  /* to center vertically */
  height:100vh;
  align-items:center;
}
a { text-decoration: none; }
.button-one {
    background: #edf000; /* background color */
}
.button-two {
    background: #f15640;
}
.button-three {
    background: #27c9b8;
}
.button-one,
.button-two,
.button-three {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.button-one:hover,
.button-two:hover,
.button-three:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a class="button-one" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Click Me</a>
  <a class="button-two" title="Relevant Title" href="#">No Click Me</a>
  <a class="button-three" title="Relevant Title" href="#">No Me LOL</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to be in the center of the page like in the middle of the screen (if this is what you had in mind), you can use flex for that and vh for element height, like this:

```css
.links {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}
a { text-decoration: none; }
.button-one {
    background: #edf000; /* background color */
}
.button-two {
    background: #f15640;
}
.button-three {
    background: #27c9b8;
}
.button-one,
.button-two,
.button-three {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.button-one:hover,
.button-two:hover,
.button-three:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <div class="links">
<a class="button-one" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Click Me</a>

<a class="button-two" title="Relevant Title" href="#">No Click Me</a>

<a class="button-three" title="Relevant Title" href="#">No Me LOL</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work as well.

```css
a { text-decoration: none; }
.button-one {
    background: #edf000; /* background color */
}
.button-two {
    background: #f15640;
}
.button-three {
    background: #27c9b8;
}
.button-one,
.button-two,
.button-three {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.button-one:hover,
.button-two:hover,
.button-three:hover {
    background: #fff;
}

.center-buttons {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="center-buttons">
<a class="button-one" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Click Me</a>

<a class="button-two" title="Relevant Title" href="#">No Click Me</a>

<a class="button-three" title="Relevant Title" href="#">No Me LOL</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapp anchor tags in a `.container` then use `position: absolute` and `width: max-content` for that:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: max-content;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-one {
  background: #edf000;
  /* background color */
}

.button-two {
  background: #f15640;
}

.button-three {
  background: #27c9b8;
}

.button-one,
.button-two,
.button-three {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.button-one:hover,
.button-two:hover,
.button-three:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="button-one" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Click Me</a>

  <a class="button-two" title="Relevant Title" href="#">No Click Me</a>

  <a class="button-three" title="Relevant Title" href="#">No Me LOL</a>
</div>
```